# How can I improve a broadband USB stick's speed?

Tags: usb, hsdpa

I have a broadband USB stick. I know that it's very signal dependent. Does anyone know any tips and tricks on how I can improve its speed and performance?

Comment: An external antenna.

Comment: External antenna? How?

Comment: Closely examine the stick for any hatches and if you find any, open them. If you're lucky, you'll find a connector for an antenna. It looks like the ones on [this](http://www.laptoprepair101.com/wp-images/wi-fi-card/connect-wireless-antenna.jpg) picture, but there are other types too. Connect an external antenna to it and you should have better signal. You could also try searching for 3G antenna for example and find an antenna. If you don't have a antenna connector, you're out of luck.

Comment: If you don't have an antenna connector, maybe this would work: http://www.mobilefun.co.uk/clip-antenna-for-3g-usb-modems-universal-p18117.htm

Comment: Try a [Wok-Fi](http://www.usbwifi.orconhosting.net.nz/).

Comment: Maybe not portable but...  http://www.wired.com/culture/lifestyle/multimedia/2004/08/64440?slide=2&slideView=5